# The frame counter of my Nikon FA (analog) is broken. How to activate the light measurement regardless?

Tags: nikon, film, repair

For some reason the counter doesn't go forward anymore, but, the film is rolling, and the film is being exposed, but the LCD constantly shows the "C250" message, which indicates that it's firing the shutter at a fixed speed of 250, until the first two frames of film are properly rolled. The problem is that no matter how many times I expose and advance the film, counter stays behind 1, and LCD shows "C25"

Comment: I'm not sure on this, hence it's not an answer, but couldn't you sacrifice one frame to check if everything is working? You could unscrew the lens, such that you see the mirror, then set the shutter speed to `B` and click & hold the shutter. If you can see the mirror rise, the shutter open and the film itself then you can assume that the mechanism works. Given that the film is rolling this means that every photo you take is exposed.

Comment: Good idea, but What I really want is for the camera to do the light measurement, but I notice that It's always at "C250", which means it's waiting for me to do the first 2 dummy exposures (that's what I read in the NIKON FA user manual.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I still follow... So are you worried that the film is not exposed or that the camera is not measuring correctly? If it's the latter you should rephrase your question considerably.

Comment: I fiddled around with the camera a bit more, and _Now_ I know that the film is exposed, but the measurement is off (I'll make an edit)

Comment: Well, you sort of found your problem. The camera is programmed to set the shutter speed to 1/250 as long as you don't pass the first frame. While you physically do so, the frame counter is stuck at 1, so the camera never thinks it's going further. I think your question should be on how to fix the frame counter.

Comment: yup, how to fix the counter, or maybe a way to activate the light measurement without the counter working properly

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but you can find a PDF of the FA service manual here: http://arcticwolfs.net/

Comment: Oh my God, long live the digital world... I'm into repairing stuff myself, but this is NASA-grade complexity.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the little metal tab that depresses when you close the film door may not be engaged properly by the door when closed (e.g. if the door is bent slightly). This 'finger' is a small metal tab located in the dust seal track just below and to the left of the film advance crank. If this tab is not depressed fully, the film counter will not advance when you wind on. To test this, take the (empty) camera and open the back, then use a small screwdriver or similar to hold the metal tab down while you shoot and advance a few frames. If you do this and the frame counter still does not work, then it's possible (as you suggest) that the film advance is damaged and not working properly. In this case, it requires professional attention to fix, though spare parts for this model are long discontinued.
Even if you have some camera repair experience I do not suggest removing the top plate and attempting repairs on this camera yourself, as you will find delicate light meter wires and a complicated knob/viewfinder pulley system to contend with (one of these pulleys is possibly where the fault lies).

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the mirror and the shutter, i.e. the stuff that makes the noise when you hit the shutter button.

Comment: @mattdm The OP states `the film is rolling`. I assume he deduced that from the winder turning when he cocked the lever.

Comment: I know for a fact that the film is advancing, because the rewind knob is rotating as I rotate the advance handler.